# python filter lxml

Tags: python, lxml

i using someone code to create a filter.

```
import urllib2
import lxml.html as lh

req = urllib2.Request("http://www.ip-adress.com/ip_tracer/157.123.22.11", headers={'User-Agent' : "Magic Browser"})
html = urllib2.urlopen(req).read()
doc=lh.fromstring(html)
print ''.join(doc.xpath('.//*[@class="odd"]')[-1].text_content().split())
```

it will output Organization:ZenithDataSystems.
but when i run it, it shows some errors

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "ext.py", line 2, in ?
import lxml.html as lh
File "/usr/lib64/python2.4/site-packages/lxml/html/__init__.py", line 42, in ?
from lxml import etree
ImportError: /usr/lib64/python2.4/site-packages/lxml/etree.so: undefined symbol:       xmlMemDisplayLast
```

I didn't use the lxml before. My python version is 2.4.3 and OS is CentOS release 5.5
how to solve it.
when i update the lxml version, it shows

```
      Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "ext.py", line 3, in ?
      req= urllib2.Requset("http:// www.ip-address.com/ip_tracer/157.123.22.11", headers={'User-Agent' : "Magic Browser"})
      AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'Requset'
```

Thanks,

Comment: How did you install lxml? The version of python you are using (2.4) is quite old.

Comment: Maybe you can upgrade your lxml first via 
    
    pip install --upgrade lxml

Comment: @waitingkuo, when i upgrade lxml, it shows Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "ext.py", line 3, in ?
    req= urllib2.Requset("http:// www.ip-address.com/ip_tracer/157.123.22.11", headers={'User-Agent' : "Magic Browser"})
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'Requset'
?

Answer (score 0):

It's a [bug](https://github.com/lxml/lxml/issues/71).You need upgrade to `lxml 3.0.1` (or downgrade to `lxml 2.3.6`).

```
pip install -U lxml==3.0.1
```

[lxml 3.0.1](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/lxml/3.0.1) bugfix `GH#71: Failure to work with libxml2 2.6.x.`

Comment: When i upgrade lxml, it showsTraceback (most recent call last):
  File "ext.py", line 3, in ?
    req= urllib2.Requset("http:// www.ip-address.com/ip_tracer/157.123.22.11", headers={'User-Agent' : "Magic Browser"})
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'Requset'

Comment: You made a typo. Look carefully: "Requset"